# if statements in a respond_to js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery, partial-views

I have a page that has ajax tabs that loads different actions in my controller to render a partial with different content.

So the index action of my controller has two remote: true links at the top. Wich works fine, they render the corresponding partial appropriately using the respond_to js.

```
#comments_stream.js.erb and likes_stream.js.erb
$("#masonry-container").html("<%= escape_javascript render('activities/activites') %>");
```

The problem is I am also paginating these partials kaminari and infinite scroll. so I dont want to run the code in the js.erb file above when my pagination fires because its just replacing (.html) my content instead of appending the new content the way infinite scroll script is trying to do (and does on my other pages).

```
#pagination
<%= paginate @activities, remote: true %>
```

So, my real question is how can I make the .html("<%... only fire when the link in my tab is clicked and not when the pagination is fired.

I tried to target the remote action with a paramater, but couldn't get it to work.

```
 #original remote link
<%= link_to comments_stream_path, remote: true %>

#what I tried
<%= link_to comments_stream_path, remote: true, :item => 'comments_partial' %>

#comments.js.erb
<% if params[:item] == 'comments_partial' %>
  $("#masonry-container").html("<%= escape_javascript render('activities/activites') %>");
<% end %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been messing with this for a while now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are passing wrong your parameter, try:

```
<%= link_to comments_stream_path(:item => 'comments_partial'), remote: true %>
```